# Facebook Android SDK 4.0.1 What is the App Call ID?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using the Facebook SDK for android to post a photo to facebook, and i use `FacebookBroadcastReceiver` to later get confirmation that the post succeded, and my goal is to get that post id.

I noticed that because i share a photo, facebook always takes the upload to the background hence `FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>` callback `onSuccess(Sharer.Result result)` always gets `result.getPostId()` as `null`, but unfortunately `FacebookBroadcastReceiver`'s `onSuccessfulAppCall(String appCallId, String action, Bundle extras)` dont give me access to the post id either (afaik), i am assuming there is a way to use `appCallId` to get the post id, anyone knows how? or is there another way to get the post? whats this app call id purpose for the SDK user anyway?

Answer (score -1):

At this time the SDK does not return the object ID of the completed image upload. If you inspect e.g. the `Bundle` in [`HelloFacebookBroadcastReceiver. onSuccessfulAppCall(String, String, Bundle)`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookBroadcastReceiver.java#L34) at runtime, you'll find that it contains nothing more than what the `appCallId` and `action` give you already.

Additionally, there is no way for your app to know which `appCallId` will be used beforehand. Because of this, you cannot create e.g. a progress bar in your app that completes when the photo was indeed uploaded.